# Chrome Driver Headless to save us the html and resources

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, headless, google-chrome-headless

I'm looking to programmatically download the webpage output to save us html and also resources css and js and images used on the webpage, Is it possible with chrome driver?

Anybody did any functionality similar using ChromeDriver headless or any other pointers or sample code references would be appreciated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did a few investigations, Out of the box Chrome Driver, due to security reason this feature not enabled to download all the resources and HTML by save-as using Chrome driver.

I have started creating a separate project myself to download all the resources and HTML using Chrome driver, still fine tuning this project for better, maybe this code can be useful at the starting point.

```
 [TestMethod]
 public void DownloadSingpleWebPageAndResources()
 {
            List<PageInfo> pageInfos = new List<PageInfo>();
            pageInfos.Add(new PageInfo() { PageTcmId = "12-12335", DownloadUri = new Uri("https://www.test.com/en/index.html") });

            bool found = false;
            var client = new ChromeDriverClientRequest("JOB-12-TEST1", pageInfos);
            client.PackageGenerationFolderPath = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\temp");
            client.DownloadWebsitePageResources();
            found = true;

            Assert.IsTrue(found, "The item was not resolved");
 }

public sealed class ChromeDriverClientRequest : IDisposable
{
    public IWebProxy proxy { set; get; }
    public string JobId { set; get; }
    public List<PageInfo> PageInfos { set; get; }

    private DirectoryInfo _packageGenerationFolderPath;

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the destination folder path.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>The destination folder path.</value>
    public DirectoryInfo PackageGenerationFolderPath
    {
        get
        {
            if (_packageGenerationFolderPath != null && !_packageGenerationFolderPath.Exists)
            {
                _packageGenerationFolderPath.Create();
            }

            return _packageGenerationFolderPath;
        }
        set => _packageGenerationFolderPath = value;
    }

    public ChromeDriverClientRequest()
    {

    }

    public ChromeDriverClientRequest(string jobId, List<PageInfo> pageInfos)
    {
        JobId = jobId;
        PageInfos = pageInfos;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// DownloadWebsitePage
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public void DownloadWebsitePageResources()
    {
        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        options.AddArgument("--window-size=1920,1080");
        options.AddArgument("--disable-gpu");
        options.AddArgument("--disable-extensions");
        options.AddArgument("--proxy-server='direct://'");
        options.AddArgument("--proxy-bypass-list=*");
        options.AddArgument("--start-maximized");
        options.AddArgument("--headless");
        options.AddArgument("no-sandbox");
        options.AcceptInsecureCertificates = true;
        options.PageLoadStrategy = PageLoadStrategy.Normal;

        ChromeDriver driver = null;

        try
        {
            //Create a assets folder
            string path = Path.Combine(PackageGenerationFolderPath.FullName, JobId, "assets");
            if (!Directory.Exists(path))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
            }

            driver = new ChromeDriver(options);

            foreach (PageInfo page in PageInfos)
            {
                driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(page.DownloadUri);
                object html = driver.ExecuteScript("return document.body.parentElement.outerHTML");

                HtmlDocument htmlDoc = new HtmlDocument();
                htmlDoc.LoadHtml(html.ToString());

                ProcessImagesToDownload(ref htmlDoc, page);
                ProcessHtml5ImagesTagsToDownload(ref htmlDoc, page);
                ProcessStylesheetsToDownload(ref htmlDoc, page);
                ProcessScriptsToDownload(ref htmlDoc, page);
                SaveProcessedHtmlFile(ref htmlDoc, page);
            }

            createZipFile();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception(ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            if(driver!=null)
                driver.Quit();
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="zipPath"></param>
    /// <param name="archiveFileName"></param>
    private void createZipFile()
    {
        string DirectoryToBeArchive = Path.Combine(PackageGenerationFolderPath.FullName, JobId);
        string DirectoryToBeArchiveZipFileName = Path.Combine(PackageGenerationFolderPath.FullName, JobId + ".zip");

        if (File.Exists(DirectoryToBeArchiveZipFileName))
        {
            File.Delete(DirectoryToBeArchiveZipFileName);
            ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory(DirectoryToBeArchive, DirectoryToBeArchiveZipFileName, CompressionLevel.Fastest, false);
        }
        else
        {
            ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory(DirectoryToBeArchive, DirectoryToBeArchiveZipFileName, CompressionLevel.Fastest, false);
        }

        Directory.Delete(DirectoryToBeArchive, true);
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Save Processed Html File
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="htmlDoc"></param>
    /// <param name="page"></param>

    private void SaveProcessedHtmlFile(ref HtmlDocument htmlDoc, PageInfo page)
    {
        string htmlSourceFiname = Path.GetFileName(page.DownloadUri.ToString());

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Path.GetExtension(page.DownloadUri.ToString())))
        {
            htmlSourceFiname = htmlSourceFiname.Replace(Path.GetExtension(page.DownloadUri.ToString()), ".html");
        }
        else if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(htmlSourceFiname))
        {
            htmlSourceFiname = htmlSourceFiname + ".html";
        }
        else
        {
            htmlSourceFiname = "index.html";
        }

        using (FileStream sw = new FileStream(Path.Combine(PackageGenerationFolderPath.FullName, JobId, page.PageTcmId + "_" + htmlSourceFiname), FileMode.Create))
        {
            htmlDoc.Save(sw);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Process Images To Download
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="htmlDoc"></param>
    /// <param name="page"></param>
    private void ProcessImagesToDownload(ref HtmlDocument htmlDoc, PageInfo page)
    {
        HtmlNodeCollection imagesNodes = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//img");
        if (imagesNodes != null)
        {
            foreach (HtmlNode node in imagesNodes)
            {
                if (node.Attributes["src"] != null)
                {
                    string url = node.Attributes["src"].Value;

                    if (url.Contains("?"))
                    {
                        url = url.Substring(0, node.Attributes["src"].Value.IndexOf("?"));
                    }

                    if (url.StartsWith("//"))
                    {
                        url = string.Format("{0}:{1}", page.DownloadUri.Scheme, url);
                    }

                    if (IsAbsoluteUrl(url))
                    {
                        Uri uri = new Uri(url);

                        if (string.Compare(page.DownloadUri.Host, uri.Host, true) == 0)
                        {
                            DonwloadBinaryResource(uri);
                            node.Attributes["src"].Value = "./assets/" + Path.GetFileName(url);
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        DonwloadBinaryResource(new UriBuilder(page.DownloadUri.Scheme, page.DownloadUri.Host, page.DownloadUri.Port, url).Uri);
                        node.Attributes["src"].Value = "./assets/" + Path.GetFileName(node.Attributes["src"]!=null?node.Attributes["src"].Value.ToString():"");
                    }

                }
            }
        }

    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Process Html5 Images Tags To Download
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="htmlDoc"></param>
    /// <param name="page"></param>
    private void ProcessHtml5ImagesTagsToDownload(ref HtmlDocument htmlDoc, PageInfo page)
    {
        HtmlNodeCollection imagesNodes = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//source");
        if (imagesNodes != null)
        {
            foreach (HtmlNode node in imagesNodes)
            {
                if (node.Attributes["srcset"] != null)
                {
                    string url = node.Attributes["srcset"].Value;

                    if (url.Contains("?"))
                    {
                        url = url.Substring(0, node.Attributes["srcset"].Value.IndexOf("?"));
                    }

                    if (url.StartsWith("//"))
                    {
                        url = string.Format("{0}:{1}", page.DownloadUri.Scheme, url);
                    }

                    if (IsAbsoluteUrl(url))
                    {
                        Uri uri = new Uri(url);

                        if (string.Compare(page.DownloadUri.Host, uri.Host, true) == 0)
                        {
                            DonwloadBinaryResource(uri);
                            node.Attributes["srcset"].Value = "./assets/" + Path.GetFileName(url);
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        DonwloadBinaryResource(new UriBuilder(page.DownloadUri.Scheme, page.DownloadUri.Host, page.DownloadUri.Port, url).Uri);
                        node.Attributes["srcset"].Value = "./assets/" + Path.GetFileName(node.Attributes["srcset"]!=null?node.Attributes["srcset"].Value.ToString():"");
                    }

                }
            }
        }

    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Process Stylesheets To Download
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="htmlDoc"></param>
    /// <param name="page"></param>
    private void ProcessStylesheetsToDownload(ref HtmlDocument htmlDoc, PageInfo page)
    {
        HtmlNodeCollection linkNodes = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//link[@rel=\"stylesheet\"]");
        if (linkNodes != null)
        {
            foreach (HtmlNode node in linkNodes)
            {
                if (node.Attributes["href"] != null)
                {
                    string url = node.Attributes["href"].Value;

                    if (url.Contains("?"))
                    {
                        url = url.Substring(0, node.Attributes["href"].Value.IndexOf("?"));
                    }

                    if (url.StartsWith("//"))
                    {
                        url = string.Format("{0}:{1}", page.DownloadUri.Scheme, url);
                    }

                    if (!url.StartsWith("http"))
                    {
                        url = new UriBuilder(page.DownloadUri.Scheme, page.DownloadUri.Host, page.DownloadUri.Port, url).Uri.ToString();
                    }

                    if (IsAbsoluteUrl(url))
                    {
                        Uri uri = new Uri(url);

                        if (string.Compare(page.DownloadUri.Host, uri.Host, true) == 0)
                        {
                            DonwloadResource(uri);
                            node.Attributes["href"].Value = "./assets/" + Path.GetFileName(url);
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        DonwloadResource(new UriBuilder(page.DownloadUri.Scheme, page.DownloadUri.Host, page.DownloadUri.Port, url).Uri);
                        node.Attributes["href"].Value = "./assets/" + Path.GetFileName(url);
                    }

                }
            }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Process Scripts To Download
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="htmlDoc"></param>
    /// <param name="page"></param>
    private void ProcessScriptsToDownload(ref HtmlDocument htmlDoc, PageInfo page)
    {
        HtmlNodeCollection scriptNodes = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//script");
        if (scriptNodes != null)
        {
            foreach (HtmlNode node in scriptNodes)
            {
                if (node.Attributes["src"] != null)
                {
                    string url = node.Attributes["src"].Value;

                    if (url.Contains("?"))
                    {
                        url = url.Substring(0, node.Attributes["src"].Value.IndexOf("?"));
                    }

                    if (!url.StartsWith("http"))
                    {
                        url = new UriBuilder(page.DownloadUri.Scheme, page.DownloadUri.Host, page.DownloadUri.Port, url).Uri.ToString();
                    }

                    if (IsAbsoluteUrl(url))
                    {
                        Uri uri = new Uri(url);

                        if (string.Compare(page.DownloadUri.Host, uri.Host, true) == 0)
                        {
                            DonwloadResource(uri);
                            node.Attributes["src"].Value = "./assets/" + Path.GetFileName(url);
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        DonwloadResource(new UriBuilder(page.DownloadUri.Scheme, page.DownloadUri.Host, page.DownloadUri.Port, url).Uri);
                        node.Attributes["src"].Value = "./assets/" + Path.GetFileName(url);
                    }

                }
            }
        }
    }

    private bool IsAbsoluteUrl(string url)
    {
        return Uri.TryCreate(url, UriKind.Absolute, out Uri result);
    }

    private void DonwloadBinaryResource(Uri uri)
    {
        string resourcePathFileName = Path.Combine(PackageGenerationFolderPath.FullName, JobId, "assets", Path.GetFileName(uri.ToString()));
        if (!File.Exists(resourcePathFileName))
        {
            // Download file
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
            request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/30.0.1599.69 Safari/537.36";

            //proxy
            if (proxy != null)
            {
                request.Proxy = proxy;
            }

            using (WebResponse response = request.GetResponse())
            {
                using (BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
                {
                    // Read file 
                    byte[] bytes = reader.ReadAllBytes();

                    // Write to local folder 
                    using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(resourcePathFileName, FileMode.Create))
                    {
                        fs.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Donwload Resource
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="url"></param>
    private void DonwloadResource(Uri url)
    {
        string resourcePathFileName = Path.Combine(PackageGenerationFolderPath.FullName, JobId, "assets", Path.GetFileName(url.ToString()));
        if (!File.Exists(resourcePathFileName))
        {
            using (WebClient webClient = new WebClient())
            {
                webClient.Headers.Add("UserAgent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/30.0.1599.69 Safari/537.36");
                if (proxy != null)
                {
                    webClient.Proxy = proxy;
                }

                webClient.DownloadFileAsync(url, resourcePathFileName);
            }
        }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        //TODO
    }
}
```

I hope it helps

Answer (score 2):

To get the HTML of the page you can use:

```
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.getPageSource();
```

In order to use the ChromeDriver headless mode, add the following lines before the WebDriver declaration:

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.setHeadless(true);
```

or:

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("--headless");
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer,  I'm aware of this, getPageSource - we can't get the ajax executed HTML, that's why I did try to get the HTML after dom execution.